# Programatically write variable names along with their data type to Teradata using R?

Tags: sql, r, teradata

I am attempting to write a dataframe using R to Teradata. The dataframe is wide in format (over 100 columns) and writing to Teradata implies declaring both the name and class of each variable. Note that the below data is just serving as an example.

```
iris$integerRandom <- seq_along(iris$Sepal.Length) 
iris$Dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2018-01-01"), by = "d", length.out = nrow(iris))
iris$Dates2 <- seq.Date(as.Date("2019-01-01"), by = "d", length.out = nrow(iris))
iris$Species <- as.character(iris$Species)
iris$characterRandom <- sample(letters, nrow(iris), replace = TRUE)

## Getting Numeric and Integer Names first

names_num <- names(iris)[which(sapply(iris, class) %in% c("integer", "numeric"))]
names_date <- names(iris)[which(sapply(iris, class) %in% "Date")]
names_character <- names(iris)[which(sapply(iris, class) %in% "character")]


## Generating variable names with corresponding variable types

paste(gsub("varchar(300)", '"varchar(300)"', gsub(",", " = varchar(300), ", toString(names_character))), "varchar(300)", sep = " = ")
paste(gsub(",", " = date", toString(names_date)), " = date")
paste(gsub("varchar(300)", '"float"', gsub(",", " = float, ", toString(names_num))), "float", sep = " = ")
```

Ideally, I would like the desired output to say 
Species = "varchar(300)",  characterRandom = "varchar(300)", and so forth. Note that the order in which the variables is important as the order matters when declaring the names and the types to Teradata (or SQL in this case) the code will probably work for both tools. So the order of the variable names along with 
Sepal.Length and end with characterRandom.

Comment: I am not sure but do you need something like `c(paste0(names_character, " = varchar(300)"), paste0(names_date, " = date"), paste0(names_num, " = float"))` ?

Comment: There's a relatively new package dplyr.teradata that might be helpful.